# NVIDIA Grid / Gaming drivers licensing issues AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2019, nvidia

I'm following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/install-nvidia-driver.html#nvidia-gaming-driver in order to install NVIDIA Gaming drivers to unlock higher resolutions on AWS EC2 on a g4dn.xlarge instance.

Everything is going smoothly, the driver download, the installation, the license download, etc. but somehow when I ran nvidia-smi to check the license for Product Name it says "NVIDIA Virtual Desktops" instead of "NVIDIA Cloud Gaming".

Also the biggest annoyance is that, unlike the default windows driver (which also support high resolutions but certain 3D applications and games require the NVIDIA drivers) 1/4 of the screen is blackened which seems a way for NVIDIA to mess with clients if they aren't properly licensed. Which is baffling. (see screenshot below)

Does anybody know what could be going wrong here? I get no errors, everything installs smoothly and comes from the legitimate source. I have the GridSwCert.txt in C:\Users\Public\Documents and it does contain the license so I'm completely lost here.

All I can do is revert to Windows' default video drivers.

[image]